# Which is efficient among a loop that is executed once with two comparison or a loop executed twice with one comparison?

Tags: loops, time-complexity

I am trying to find the smallest and second smallest number in an array. I can scan twice or I can scan once with two comparision. Which is efficient?

Comment: Which language are you using? Haven't you tried to compare using system's current time in ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scan should be faster, as you can just keep two separete variables for smallest and second smallest. You will use, *on avarage*, less than two comparisons per iterate (as compared to 2x separate loops using exactly 2x number of single-loop comparisons).

In some kind of pseudocode

```
smallest = Inf
2ndSmallest = Inf
for elem in array
    if elem < smallest
        2ndSmallest = smallest
        smallest = elem
    else if elem < 2ndSmallest
        2ndSmallest = elem
    end
end
```

Where this assumes that you enter the if clauses above at totally least twice (you can easily add a fix for cases where this might not be the case). The discussion were, however, which to prefer, so I'll leave writing up the actual comparison implementation for you as an exercise.

Comment: @Elias Please give me some more detailed feedback and I can possibly correct this, as well as learn something myself.

Comment: Now, after your edition, is almost correct. If the array is `[1,1,2]`, `smallest` and `2ndSmallest` will be `1`.

Comment: @Elias Thanks for your feedback. I'll just edit the assumption before the code, just pseudocode for the author the see why this should be preferred over separate loops.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: avoid multiple loops

Second rule of thumb: avoid premature optimization (readable and maintainable first)

That said, pseudo code for efficient algorithm

(Note that you need to handle the case where list size is empty or one):

```
smallest = min(list[0],list[1])
second_smallest = max(list[0],list[1])
for el in list[2:]:
    if el < second_smallest:
        second_smallest = max(el,smallest)
        smallest = min(el,smallest)
```

Comment: Isn't avoidance of multiple loops an instance of premature optimization? I read about it in computer architectures. They say that you loose caching if iterate muliple times. Focus on a piece of array and do as much job as possible before advancing further. But exploiting the system cache is a premature optimization and is bad, therefore.

Comment: Yes but multiple loops also affects readability. So, the point is, focus on readability and maintainability first. Then, if you are looking to optimize, a general rule of thumb is looping is more expensive then... not.